# Is "durch diese Weise" incorrect?

Tags: preposition, expression

While it would be usual to say, "auf/in diese/r Weise", [DWDS has this sentence](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=bundestag&q=durch%20dieser%20Weise):

> **Durch diese Weise** sind zum Beispiel die verschiedenen Hunderassen für die Jagd entstanden.

Is this a valid option, infrequently used, or simply wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the phrase just a bit unusual. I note, that *Vorgehensweise* is rather  frequently used in combination with *durch* and that *Weise* on its own may be considered as a partial omission or as the generic category.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I consider this wrong. The idiom is *auf diese Weise* or *in dieser Weise*.

The quoted sentence, which uses *durch diese Weise*, is from a politician's oral speech in the German Bundestag. It was included in the plenary protocol and thus made it into one of the text corpora of the DWDS.

Comment: Isn't it remarkable how even native speakers possessing above average language skills can still make such errors? I wonder if the speaker of this sentence, if accused of the error, would even acknowledge it? Or is this type of error generally accepted and ignored in normal communications?

Comment: I am sure that I make dozens of such errors while in the flow of speaking orally, and that most listeners simply ignore them.

Comment: Two remarks: **1.** the transcript of that debate contains four times the phrase “auf diese Weise” and only once “durch diese Weise”. **2.** The MP who said this, Heinrich-Wilhelm Ronsöhr, is from a small village in rural Lower Saxony, so this may well be a dialect thing.